# How to build an array when Java REST Web Service starts

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey

I have method in my web service which loads the same mySQL data into an array every time it is called. It's a fairly large amount of data and it would be much more efficient if this could be done once when the service is started, instead of for every single request.

I've searched around but can't see any examples of how to achieve this, is it possible and if so - how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do it something like

```
private static List<Items> data;

public static List<Items> getData() {
   if(data==null) {
        //get from db
   }
   return data;
}
```

this way you will only have one trip to the database to populate the data. Alternatively since you are using Jersey you could extend [`Application`](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.4/jersey/com/sun/jersey/spi/container/servlet/package-summary.html) and populate you data that way when registering the classes

```
   <init-param>
       <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
       <param-value>com.foo.MyApplication</param-value>
   </init-param>
```

Comment: I had tried that in the path resource, but "data" was always null and it would reload - is there a specific place to do this?

Comment: Ah, sorry, brainfart there - I'm actually using Jackson, not Jersey. Does the second option still apply?

Comment: All good. Tried your first solution again and it worked this time - I must have done something wrong first time around.